# Can't run flutter app with firebase on IOS as it giving error

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics, flutter-dependencies

Integrating Firebase in my flutter app. For Android it works fine but for IOS it gives an error

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           22.9s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
*** First throw call stack:
  (
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c710bc +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
     3   Runner                              0x00000001063194ea +[FIRApp configure] + 138
     4   Runner                              0x00000001063eb446 -[FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin init] + 214
     5   Runner                              0x00000001063eb27d +[FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 173
     6   Runner                              0x00000001063144e3 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 115
     7   Runner                  <…>
```

I added GoogleService-Info.plist under Runner by right click on Runner and Add the files using XCode! and its showing inside Runner/Runner folder.

[image]

[image]

But it still not working and crash as app start on emulator.

AppDelegate.swift code is:-

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
   override func application(
      _ application: UIApplication,
      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
      ) -> Bool {
         FirebaseApp.configure()
         GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
         return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
   }
}
```

What I am missing due to still getting error?

I added `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` in bottom of `Podfile`

Comment: did you add your firebase stuff to the pod file?

Comment: @Edin yes added....i added that in question also

Comment: What firebase product do you use for example if you use cloud firestore you need to add that to the podfile

Comment: I am using firebase analytics...i need to add something for that?

Comment: so in your app you only use firebase analytics?And also where did you add firebase to the podfile?

Comment: yes using only firebase analytics....added the line pod 'Firebase/Analytics' in the end of Podfile

Comment: there we have the problem you need to put the firebase stuff under the line: # Plugin Pods

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: if yes please upvote my answer

Comment: same error any solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559857/flutter-app-crash-after-launch-on-simulator?noredirect=1#comment110634735_62559857